# ERROR No switch is currently set. Please use 'opam switch' to set or install a switch

Tags: node, updates

We are currently receiving these kind of error messages when updating our tezos node.

Our upgrading procedure are like this:
1. We copy the main ~/tezos directory to a new directory called ~/tezos-new. 
2. Call update command as shown below.
3. Stop node, change directory names, and start node again.

Using this command:

> cd ~/tezos-new && eval $(opam env) && make clean && git checkout
>   mainnet && git pull && make clean && make build-deps && eval $(opam
>   env) && make && cd ~

We get errors like this:

```
[ERROR] No switch is currently set. Please use 'opam switch' to set or install a switch
make: dune: Command not found
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: [clean] Error 127 (ignored)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/tezos/tezos-new/docs'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tezos/tezos-new/docs'
Already on 'mainnet'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mainnet'.
Already up to date.
[ERROR] No switch is currently set. Please use 'opam switch' to set or install a switch
make: dune: Command not found
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: [clean] Error 127 (ignored)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/tezos/tezos-new/docs'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tezos/tezos-new/docs'
[ERROR] No switch is currently set. Please use 'opam switch' to set or install a switch
[tezos] Initialised
```

Any insight is much appreciated.

In the end the node is updated, and is running latest block and everything. Just wanted to get more insight into this message. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should run `opam init` first in the new directory to initialize opam env and that will also set opam switch

Comment: Then it ask me to modify "~/.profile" so that eval$(opam env) isn't required every time I want access the opam installation. Saying yes to this still gives me the switch error message at the beginning. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Did you copy ~/tezos to ~/tezos-new without cleaning-up the build-artifacts?

If there is an `_opam` subdirectory in ~/tezos and you try to copy it to ~/tezos-new you may confuse opam (because the _opam directories are not relocatable).

Comment: Yes that must be it. Thanks for the advice.